# What I think should be a simple plot

Tags: graph, matplotlib

So basically I am trying to plot a graph with n on my x axis and r on my y axis

So for n=1 it has r=1, n=2 it has r=2, n=3 it has r=4, n=4 it has 8,.and then i plan to extend it.

I tried this:

```
import scipy
import scipy.linalg
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


for n in range(1,5):
    A=np.identity(n)
    for i in range(0,n):
        for j in range(0,i):
            A[i,j]=-1
    A[:,n-1]=1
    x=np.random.randn(n,1)
    b=A*x
    P, L, U = scipy.linalg.lu(A)
    print A
    r=U.max()/A.max()
    print r
    print n
    plt.plot(n,r)
    plt.show()
```

But it only plots the greatest value of n against the corresponding value of r rather than all values of n. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do `n` and `r` represent? That is, what is the plot meant to show?

Comment: n is the dimension of the matrix A (and therefore U) and then r is the ratio of the max element of U to the max element of A, and I wanted to show that as the dimension (n) increases, this ratio (r) increases exponentially. So I wanted to plot r for a range of n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you first need to create the array to plot and then plot it

```
rr, nn = [], []
for n in range(1,5):
    A=np.identity(n)
    for i in range(0,n):
        for j in range(0,i):
            A[i,j]=-1
    A[:,n-1]=1
    x=np.random.randn(n,1)
    b=A*x
    P, L, U = scipy.linalg.lu(A)
    print A
    r=U.max()/A.max()
    print r
    print n
    rr.append(r)
    nn.append(n)

plt.plot(nn,rr)
plt.show()
```

The way you do creates a new plot with one point each loop.

Besides, if you plan to increase `n`, I suggest to check for more efficient ways of loopings (e.g. list comprehension or [itertools](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html))

Answer (score 1):

`plt.plot()` can plot lines and markers. By default it will plot lines only. You only give a single point so no lines *can* be drawn and the markers *won't* be drawn. To turn on the markers set the attribute `marker="o"`: `plt.plot(x, y, markers="o")`.
If you want a line plot, you'll have to make lists of `n` and `r` and plot those.
For a list with markers: http://matplotlib.org/api/artist_api.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D.set_marker

Also, you may want to take `plt.show()` out of the for-loop. It makes an updated figure for every iteration, I'm not sure if you want that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you want (reading your description, I think it is, but looking at your code it looks like you're trying to do something altogether more difficult).

If you're really trying to get the sequence `1, 2, 4, 8, 16, ...` I'd encourage you to work on the whole array in one operation, rather than using a for loop. It's more expressive and is much quicker for large arrays.

Anyway:

```
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> import numpy as np
>>> 
>>> n = np.arange(5)
>>> r = 2 ** n
>>> r
array([ 1,  2,  4,  8, 16])
>>> plt.plot(n, r, 'ob')
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x102d8ee10>]
>>> plt.show()
```

[image: mpl output]